# Using exuberant ctags with JavaScript in emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, exuberant-ctags

I'm trying to use exuberant ctags with JavaScript in emacs, following the guidance here: http://mattbriggs.net/blog/2012/03/18/awesome-emacs-plugins-ctags/.

The problem is, in a case such as:

```
my_obj: {
    foo: function() { },
    bar: function() {
        this.foo();
    }
}
```

When I place the cursor on the `foo` in `this.foo`, `M-.` or `find-tag` proposes to find a tag `.foo` (instead of the correct `foo`), which obviously fails.

What am I doing wrong, or does emacs/js2-mode not support this seemingly obvious use case?

Update: I am using js2-mode.

Comment: You might want to try [tern](https://github.com/marijnh/tern) instead.

Comment: I took a look at tern, thanks for the pointer. However, it doesn't seem to like dealing with the hundreds of JS files I have when I try to do a `loadEagerly` on them--node reports too many files open.

Answer (score 0):

As part of `js.el`, `js--guess-symbol-at-point` checks to see if there's a period prior to the symbol and includes it in the search.  I'm unclear as to why it was done this way though...